# java error is: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: java, string, io

I have installed `Gradle` and i am trying to read some data from a file.

The file is

```
   A; 1;2
    B;2;3
    C;4;5
    H;5;6
.
.
.
```

and i am trying to do something special on the first 5 records

```
InputStream inputFileStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/inputFile.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
        int counter = 5;

         while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();

                String[] array;
                if(counter>=0)   
                {

                    array = line.split(";");
                    System.out.println(line);

            //      System.out.println("Hero is:  "+array[0]+"  "+array[1]+"  "+array[2]);       
                     counter--;
                }   

         }
```

The problem is that, in line

```
System.out.println("Hero is:  "+array[0]+"  "+array[1]+"  "+array[2]);
```

i face with an error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

I know, that it means i am asking to get a value outside of the array,
but i don't know why it is happening?
and how can i fix it?

For downvoters: I am using `System.out.println(array-length);`

before and after erroring line, but the strange thing is that when i have the erroring line nothing is printed?

Comment: Perhaps the split didn't give more than a single return. Try printing `array.length` to see how many elements it actually has.

Comment: that's a too optimistic split, what do you think happen for the "." lines?

Comment: Also, really, learn to use a debugger, or at least to add System.out.println lines in the code, to see what your variables contain and where the problem comes from. You shouldn't need us to diagnose that kind of problem.

Comment: @RC. That just means that OP cutted the file for this post .. just a simple "...". (at least it would make no sense to have "." in that file :D)

Comment: @JBNizet, there was the old saying from Kernighan: "The most effective debugging tool is still careful thought, coupled with judiciously placed print statements".

Comment: I have update my question

Comment: *when i have the erroring line nothing is printed?*: that is a strong indication that the line is an empty string. You have a blank line in your file.

Comment: It appears I cannot post an answer. However, add a check `if (array.length > 2)` before the `System.out.println("Hero "...)` line. It will prevent the issue. As others noted, undoubtedly the problem is a blank or malformed line in the input file.

Answer (score 0):

At the first iteration, the array size is only 1, so `array[1]` throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

You need to call `System.out.println("Hero is: "+array[0]+"  "+array[1]+"  "+array[2]);` outside of the loop.

```
InputStream inputFileStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/inputFile.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
    int counter = 5;
         while (scanner.hasNext()) {
               String line = scanner.nextLine();
               String[] array;
               if(counter>=0)   
               {
                   array = line.split(";");
                   System.out.println(line);
                   counter--;
               }
         }
System.out.println("Hero is:  "+array[0]+"  "+array[1]+"  "+array[2]);
```